# how to test open-uri url exist before processing any data

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm trying to process content from a list of links using "open-uri" in ruby (1.8.6), but the bad thing happens when I'm getting an error when one link is broken or requires authentication:

```
open-uri.rb:277:in `open_http': 404 Not Found (OpenURI::HTTPError)
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
```

or

```
C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: no address associated with hostname. (SocketError)
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
```

or

```
C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in `sysread': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in `rbuf_fill'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
from C:/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
```

is there a way to test the response (url) before processing any data?

the code is:

```
require 'open-uri'

smth.css.each do |item| 
 open('item[:name]', 'wb') do |file|
   file << open('item[:href]').read
 end
end
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of

```
    require 'open-uri'

    smth.css.each do |item|
     begin 
       open('item[:name]', 'wb') do |file|
         file << open('item[:href]').read
       end
     rescue => e
       case e
       when OpenURI::HTTPError
         # do something
       when SocketError
         # do something else
       else
         raise e
       end
      rescue SystemCallError => e
       if e === Errno::ECONNRESET
        # do something else
       else
        raise e
       end
     end
   end
```

I don't know of any way of testing the connection without opening it and trying, so rescuing these errors would be the only way I can think of. The thing to be aware of is that OpenURI::HTTPError and SocketError are both subclasses of StandardError, whereas Errno::ECONNRESET is a subclass of SystemCallError. So rescue => e won't catch Errno::ECONNRESET.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using a conditional if/else statement to check the return value of the action for "failure":

```
def controller_action
    url = "some_API"
    response = open(url).read
    data = JSON.parse(response)["data"]
    if response["status"] == "failure"
        redirect_to :action => "home" 
    else
        do_something_else
    end
end
```

Comment: This does not catch the error `SocketError (Failed to open TCP connection to jsonipsdf.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)):`